# Application Item in Navigation Bar List - Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have created an Application item - `G_FIN_YEAR`

How do I show it on the navigation bar list? I know it is created through Shared Components -> Navigation Bar list but I'm not able to show the Application item.

Please help.
I'm using apex 19.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference it as `&G_FIN_YEAR.` Note both leading ampersand `&` and trailing dot `.`